# AngularJS change model value before passing to controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, coffeescript

I need to change model value before pass its value to controller. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="MeasureCtrl as mc">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="measure" required="" 
           ng-options="m.name as m.name for m in mc.measures">
    </select>

</div>
```

It works like this:

[image]

In order to display default value(last value) of select box i need to give

> ng-model="measure" and ng-options="m.name as m.name for m in mc.measures"

You know if measure is equal to m.name then it displays measure (kg) in select box.
The problem is that when i pass data to controller it sends "kg" not its id (for example 15).
After that, another idea came to my mind and here is my approach:

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="MeasureCtrl as mc">
    <select class="form-control" ng-init="measureId = mc.getMeasureIdByName(measure)" ng-model="measure" required="" name="mc.getMeasureIdByName(measure)"
            ng-options="m.name as m.name for m in mc.measures">
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="measureId" name="measureId"/>
    {{measureId}}
</div>
```

I've had an id on me how to send measureId instead of measure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the id in your expression:

```
ng-options="m.name as m.name for m in mc.measures"
```

becomes:

```
ng-options="m.id as m.name for m in mc.measures"
```

From the docs, you need to use [[select value] as [label to show] for [item from array] in [array]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Yeah it is true that if i wrote m.id instead of m.name it sends to id to server.Why do i have written m.name because ng-model="measure" is measureName.You know ng-model value is equal m.name selectbox appears default value.